# Struggles with udev

Tags: ubuntu, udev, automounting

I want to `automount` my SD-Card on Ubuntu. I tried the following rules using `udevadm` (or `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd`).

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"
# Global mount options
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"
# Mount the device
ACTION=="add|change", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+=" echo /bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name\
} > /tmp/debug_out.txt"
#ACTION=="add|change"
# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"
# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Code from web.

```
`udevadm monitor` indicates that the card is detected

KERNEL[1778159.935932] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
KERNEL[1778159.939553] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1 (block)
KERNEL[1778159.942501] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
KERNEL[1778159.942615] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1 (block)
UDEV  [1778160.026230] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
UDEV  [1778160.101285] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1 (block)
UDEV  [1778160.184648] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
KERNEL[1778160.320013] add      /kernel/slab/ext4_inode_cache/cgroup/ext4_inode_cache(14341:systemd-udevd.service) (cgroup)
UDEV  [1778160.322555] add      /kernel/slab/ext4_inode_cache/cgroup/ext4_inode_cache(14341:systemd-udevd.service) (cgroup)
KERNEL[1778160.387280] add      /kernel/slab/fat_inode_cache/cgroup/fat_inode_cache(14341:systemd-udevd.service) (cgroup)
UDEV  [1778160.388849] add      /kernel/slab/fat_inode_cache/cgroup/fat_inode_cache(14341:systemd-udevd.service) (cgroup)
UDEV  [1778160.418509] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1 (block)
```

and output from `udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1` also looks good

```
[...]
run: '/bin/mkdir -p /media/usbhd-sdc1'
run: '/bin/mount -o relatime /dev/sdc1 /media/usbhd-sdc1'
run: '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc1'
[...]
```

However, the rules only create the directory but it does not mount the card. Executing the above rule manually with `sudo` rights works as intended (creating the directory wouldn't work with `sudo` hence this can not be the issue)

(Small followup question: I want to copy files from the card, trigger a job and `unmount` the card. Shall I do this also from `unmount` or use a different mechanism)

========================

changed everything as described below:

```
Udev/rules.d

KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block",TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=sd-automounter@%k.service
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="block",TAG+="systemd", RUN+="systemctl start sd-automounter@%k"
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"  
# Exit
```

Service description

```
# /etc/systemd/system/sd-automounter@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/sd-automounter %I(base)
```

and service

```
#!/bin/sh
# /usr/local/libexec/sd-automounter
echo "" > /tmp/debug.out
DEVICE_NAME=/dev/"$1"
echo $DEVICE_NAME >>/tmp/debug.out
udevadm info --query=property --export $DEVICE_NAME >> /tmp/debug.out
echo "" >> /tmp/debug.out
CARD_NAME=$(udevadm info --query=property --export $DEVICE_NAME | grep ID_FS_LABEL= | awk -F\' '{print $2}')
echo $CARD_NAME >> /tmp/debug.out
#CARD_NAME=$(/sbin/blkid  | grep "$DEVICE_NAME" | awk -F\" '{print $2}' |sed 's/ /_/g')
udevadm info --query=property --export /dev/sdc1
echo $CARD_NAME
mkdir -p /media/$CARD_NAME
mount -t vfat $DEVICE_NAME /media/$CARD_NAME
thanks for all help in advance
```

executing it manually `systemctl start sd-automounter@sdd1` works like a charm.

But removing and inserting nothing happens while `udevadm monitor` shows

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[1977111.519970] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
KERNEL[1977111.523252] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd1 (block)
KERNEL[1977111.526457] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
KERNEL[1977111.526572] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd1 (block)
UDEV  [1977111.612257] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
UDEV  [1977111.614914] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd1 (block)
UDEV  [1977111.697870] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd (block)
UDEV  [1977111.791344] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd1 (block)
```

Comment: If you are working on ubuntu and using `gnome` or a similar desktop environment, then you may have a conflict with `udisksd`. Can you check in the journal whether that is operating? If so, setting `ENV{DM_UDEV_DISABLE_OTHER_RULES_FLAG}="1"` may help if the rule is loadad with a priority higher than `80-udisks2.rules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the second option was that I had to use full pathes

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block",TAG+="systemd", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start sd-automounter@%k"
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="block",TAG+="systemd", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start sd-automounter@%k"
```

and use the run option also for add

Comment: I tried a dummy RUN+= lately, and only got an error in journalctl. man page says something about using only short commands. Now I see even automount works -- as long it is a `systemctl start service` hmm...

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-udev` *really* doesn't want you to mount filesystems directly from a rule any more.  You can find a lot of questions about it on this site :-).

In a recent versions of systemd, the udev service file has `SystemCallFilter=@system-service @module @raw-io`. This doesn't allow the system calls required to mount a filesystem.

(Also, I believe there's a general conflict with systemd if you *ever* directly use `mount` for a FUSE filesystem e.g. `ntfs-3g`.  If you start a FUSE server process, it is best for it to be in a dedicated systemd unit, such as a `.mount` unit.  If you let the FUSE process stay inside your current unit, then the lifetime of the FUSE process will be coupled to the lifetime of the unit you're running in).

To avoid future (or current) problems with commands in `RUN+=`, your rule can instead use `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=my-automounter@%k.service`, and then

```
# /etc/systemd/system/my-automounter@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/my-automounter %I
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# /usr/local/libexec/my-automounter

DEV=/dev/"$1"

# You can make this script as complicated as you want.
# You can read udev properties if you want, using 
# eval "$(udevadm info --query=property --export "$DEV")"
...
```

If you want to test invoking the unit manually, you could use `systemctl start my-automounter@sdc1`.

If an error occurs when systemd runs your script, you can look at error messages using `systemctl status my-automounter@*`, or `journalctl -b -u my-automounter@*`.

This also avoids you having to deal with `udev`-specific error reporting.  I think both `sh` and `systemd` have useful error reporting in case a program dies suddenly.  E.g. they should report if a program was killed by signal `SIGSYS`, due to it trying to call a system call that has been blocked using `SystemCallFilter=` :-).

Comment: Ok, rebuild everything it works using `systemctl start sd-automounter@sdd1` however `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block",TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=sd-automounter@%k.service` or `change` doesn't seem  to be executed

Comment: @CAFEBABE Ok. I am not sure what the best way to debug this is. Docs suggest if you were using `udevadm trigger /dev/sda1`, that might not work with systemd, you do need to remove and then re-add the device. But the question shows you're testing a remove+add sequence, so I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: @CAFEBABE That said, it seems like my idea is a bad hack. "systemd will only act on Wants= dependencies when a device first becomes active".  I think my idea would not work for a DVD drive.  `/dev/sr0` would only emit "change" events on media change, not "add"/"remove".

Comment: @CAFEBABE Maybe `RUN+="systemctl start sd-automounter@%k"` ?

Comment: It is still not working. I extended my question see above

Comment: >systemd-udev really doesn't want you to mount filesystems directly from a rule any more. You can find a lot of questions about it on this site :-).

I struggle finding info about this. Can you share the reasons why this approach is better than "RUN+="/usr/bin/systemd-mount ..."? Thanks

Comment: @vtronko IMO the FUSE thing is the biggest problem. Mounting an NTFS filesystem requires running a FUSE daemon process. The FUSE process needs to be moved outside the `udev` systemd service unit / cgroup, otherwise it will be killed if `udev` is restarted. The traditional `mount` command doesn't do that - it has no awareness of  `systemd`. And the traditional udev mount recipes used the `mount` command. If you instead use `RUN+="/usr/bin/systemd-mount ...`, it should avoid the problems I can think of at the moment :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi yes, I use `systemd-mount` so that mount points are in the pid 1 namespace. As I understand that indeed should cope with complications of FUSE&udev since it would be detached udev namespace from the beginning.